# How to find BigQuery dataset location in multi-region

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I would like to know about where to find the primary and backup locations of BigQuery datasets when the data is stored as multi-region? Could someone please provide me a solution for my question because I'm new to GCP BigQuery?

Any information would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any option to find where the primary and backup dataset is located if you choose multi-region. We only know that the data is stored in a single region but don't know which region[1].

If you need to store the data in a specific region, you shall use a single region[2]. In single regions, data are not backed up to other regions. To address that, you can create cross-region dataset copies[3] to enhance the disaster recovery guarantees.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/availability#multi_regions

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/availability#single_regions

[3] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets